# obb error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: disk too large for FAT12

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I've already created obb files earlier for audio files but now I'm getting this error when I try to create obb file from images. Following is the command I use:

`jobb -pn com.mypackage.appname -pv 1 -d ./input_dir -k mykeystorepass -o images.obb`

The stacktrace from the terminal is:

```
Slop: 0   Directory Overhead: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: disk too large for FAT12
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.SuperFloppyFormatter.sectorsPerCluster12(SuperFloppyFormatter.java:461)
    at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.SuperFloppyFormatter.clusterSizeFromSize(SuperFloppyFormatter.java:315)
    at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:379)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

**UPDATE** The total files in the input directory are 141 and the total size of all the files together is 3.6 MB

Comment: Sounds like you're running into the limitations of FAT12. If you look it up on wikipedia, you'll see that it doesn't support very large anything.

Comment: Did u updated anything?

Comment: FAT12 supports only upto  16 MB, the file you are about to create might be having size larger than this. This might be the problem.

Comment: But if I see the size of total files on the input directory, it's only 3.6MB with a total of 141 image files..

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your data to subdirectories. I faced the same issue when I had many files in the root directory. Moving data to subdirectories helped me to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 1):

OBB files are intended for applications with large amounts of content. It seems jobb gets confused if the amount of content is too little. For testing purposes I artificially reduced my content volume down to about 4.4MB to make device installs quicker. jobb fell over with the same error message when trying to create the OBB file.

I simply went into the directory and duplicated the directories to increase the volume to be 9.2MB and the problem went away. I'm not sure where the cut off is - I simply wanted to get on with my testing once I had made the content big enough.

An ironic case of trying to speed up my development with smaller content causing me to lose an hour or so investigating this problem.